# Question about using UDP sockets for Python group chat

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

Here is my python client script. The way it works is that each client establishes a TCP connection with the host server (in my case, an AWS server) and then the server gives them the addresses needed so the clients can communicate directly to each other via UDP.

But when I test this out with 2 clients on 2 different IPs, the messages are not received. Also, if I send "this is A" from machine A and "this is B" from machine B I will see 2 received messages on A saying "From A: this is A" and "From B: this is A". (the print is in the receiveHandler function) This tells me that there's something wrong with my socket. And in this case, machine B printed no messages at all, which is weird.

Any help is appreciated, thank you. I'll put the server script in just in case.

```
import socket
import threading

class Client:
    socket_peers = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    socket_server = socket.socket()
    peers = []

    def __init__(self, SERVER):
        self.server = SERVER
        self.socket_server.connect(SERVER)
        self.socket_peers.bind(("0.0.0.0", 5000))

    def serverHandler(self):
        while True:
            serverData = self.socket_server.recv(1024)
            serverData = serverData.decode()
            if serverData[0] == "$": # alert message
                print(serverData[1:])
            if serverData[0] == "@": # new peer
                new_peer = (serverData[1:], 5000)
                self.peers.append(new_peer)
            if serverData[0] == "^": # quit
                break

    def sendingHandler(self):
        while True:
            message = str(input(">>"))
            for peer in self.peers:
                self.socket_peers.sendto(message.encode(), peer)

    def receiveHandler(self):
        while True:
            data, addr = self.socket_peers.recvfrom(1024)
            print("From " + str(addr) + ": " + data.decode())

    def run(self):
        serverThread = threading.Thread(target=self.serverHandler)
        sendingThread = threading.Thread(target=self.sendingHandler)
        receiveThread = threading.Thread(target=self.receiveHandler)

        serverThread.start()
        sendingThread.start()
        receiveThread.start()

        serverThread.join()
        sendingThread.join()
        receiveThread.join()

        print("Goodbye.")

    def shutdown(self):
        self.socket_server.close()
        self.socket_peers.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = "123.456.789.0" # This is where I put my AWS server public IP
    port = 5000
    hostServer = (host, port)
    client = Client(hostServer)
    client.run()
    client.shutdown()
```

Here is the server script that runs on my AWS instance.

```
import socket

class Server:
    sock = socket.socket()
    clients = []
    shutdown = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 5000))

    def run(self):
        self.sock.listen(100)
        print "Listening for connections... "

        while not self.shutdown:
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            self.clients.append((conn, addr))
            self.broadcastNewPeer(addr)
            self.broadcastAlert("User: " + str(addr[0]) + " has joined.")
            print str(addr[0])

    def broadcastAlert(self, message):
        alert = "$" + message
        for client in self.clients:
            client[0].send(alert.encode())

    def broadcastNewPeer(self, addr):
        peerMsg = "@" + str(addr[0])
        for client in self.clients:
            client[0].send(peerMsg.encode())

    def broadcastForceQuit(self):
        quitMsg = "^"
        for client in self.clients:
            client[0].send(quitMsg.encode())

    def close(self):
        self.shutdown = True
        self.broadcastForceQuit()
        for client in self.clients:
            client[0].close()
        self.sock.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myServer = Server()
    myServer.run()
    print "Goodbye."
```

Comment: If your client machines are not located together on the same LAN (i.e. you are trying to send UDP packets across the Internet) then you are probably running into a fact of modern Internet life, which is that most modern Internet-client-machines are hidden behind a NAT router and/or a firewall, and either of those will typically block incoming UDP packets :(

Comment: @JeremyFriesner that's disappointing. Is there anything I can do? I really don't care about actually using this, I just want it as a resume project.

Comment: By far the easiest approach is to not use UDP; instead route all your traffic through the TCP connections the clients make to the server.  (Have the server forward data from one client to the others as necessary).  That's straightforward to implement and guaranteed to work everywhere.  But if you really want to use UDP for some reason, Google "UDP hole punching" for info on some techniques you can use to get UDP packets through NAT and firewalls (but be aware they are non-trivial to implement, and only work on certain configurations, so you'll still want TCP as a fallback)